# Becoming a Google App Engine technology partner?

Tags: google-app-engine

A large customer of mine considers to offer itself as a Google App Engine Technology partner.
Is there any publicly available documentation on the process, e.g: Acceptance criteria, Pricing, how long it takes etc.

We realize that details are only discussed with Sales Personnel. We were just looking for an overview documentation so as to roughly know what to expect.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: As a programmer creating apps to run on AppEngine I am also interested in any answers.